# Adding multiple Models into a component.

Tags: component, custom-component, model

in my component Centros I have the view and model for Hospitals, working fine. 
I want to call a general model. `general.php` located in the models folder.

```
class CentrosModelGeneral extends JModelItem
{
    protected $general;
    public function getFck()
    {
        if (!isset($this->general))
        {
            $this->general = 'Hello World!';
        }
        return $this->general;
    }
}
```

I want to access into the general model from my hospìtal component. So, inside my `function display()` I am trying this:

```
    $model = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'general', 'CentrosModel');
    var_dump ($model->get('fck'));
```

The `var_dump` gives me a `null` value. :(
What is wrong?. The `var_duymp($model);` gives me a long StdClass.

> object(CentrosModelGeneral)[360]

```
     protected 'general' => null
      protected '_item' => null
      protected '_context' => string 'group.type' (length=10)
      protected '__state_set' => null
      protected '_db' => 
     protected 'name' => string 'general' (length=7)
     protected 'option' => string 'com_centros' (length=11)
     protected 'state' =>
```

So, it looks like is working, but i dont know how to call the getFck function..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey this was a stupid question, I just needed to add:

```
    var_dump ($model->getFck());
```

Comment: There are no stupid questions -- well, maybe there are, but this one doesn't need to be labeled as such.  Let's make lemonade from lemons here.  If you ran into such a hiccup, there is a good chance that others will too.  Please take a moment to educate other Joomla users about your discovery, explain why you couldn't see what you needed and why your solution works.  This is a real opportunity to help/educate others who aren't experienced with object data.